# How to copy text from vim to an external program?

Tags: vim, clipboard, x-server

I'm trying to copy-paste some text from vim. I'm doing **v** to enter visual mode, then **y** once I selected my block.

It appears to copy the text into vim's clipboard, because p will paste it.
But in another program (e.g. Chrome), right-click->paste doesn't paste the correct text. How do I copy text to the correct clipboard?

Answer (score 103):

The following will work only if `vim --version` indicates that you have `+xterm_clipboard` feature. If not, you will have to install extra packages or recompile vim with that feature added.

---

There are actually two options for this:

```
"+y
```

copies to the "usual" clipboard buffer (so you can paste using Ctrl+V, right click and select "Paste" etc), while

```
"*y
```

copies to the X11 selection - you can paste from this buffer using middle click.

Note that `"*` and `"+` work both ways. So if you have selected some text in another application, you can paste it into vim using `"*p` and if you have copied some text (using, say, Ctrl-C) then you can paste it into vim using `"+p`.

Comment: @Tshepang it is not working from putty. what should I do ?

Comment: @RahulPatil I know not; maybe ask a separate question, perhaps on [su] (since it's a Windows tool, it would be more welcome there).

Comment: @RahulPatil - if you are using putty then you are editing the file on a remote server, not on your local machine.  Generally the remote server won't know about the clipboard on your local machine.  If you were using a Linux desktop then you can ssh with X forwarding (provided you have installed the X libraries on the server), but as putty runs on windows you don't have X running so you can't forward it.

Comment: Hello everybody,
How to type "+y ? should i type it in Visual mode or in command mode ?
Silly thing, but i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: @AlindBillore: In command mode. Literally, press the keys `shift'` then `shift=` then `y` (not all at once, one after the other, except the shifts of course).

Comment: I have `+clipboard` and `-xterm_save` . How do I get the `+xterm_clipboard`?

Comment: This answer requires gvim, but more importantly will not work if your SSH'ed into a host, even with gvim installed locally on your client system and the server system.

Answer (score 64):

**Hold down the shift** key and select text with the mouse cursor.
Text will be copied to the clipboard.

This also works for pasting *from* the clipboard in to vim.

To be clear, this works for `vim` running in a terminal such as `xterm`.

Comment: @LoopSpace for multiline selections this will also copy line numbers too when `set nu` is enabled. So u would probably want to toggle line numbers with some shortcut or run the `:set nonu` command before every selection

Comment: On MAC hold down the option key and select text with the mouse cursor

Comment: Doesn't work for me using vim 8.0 + gnome-terminal

Comment: Solution not compatible with multipane terms like tmux.

Comment: This does not copy to the clipboard, **this copies to the primary**. See the distinction in [Clipboard Arch Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard#Selections).

Comment: In vim, holding down shift, selecting the contents and using Konsole's copy shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+C) worked for me, thank you.

Comment: Another side effect of doing it this way is it copies ALL white space to the right or any line if your copying multiple lines, not ideal. @adrian Lopez, you must zoom into the specific pane you want to copy from first.

Answer (score 41):

If you are using vim >=7.3.74, then you can actually put this in your vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Which will automatically use the `+` buffer (the system clipboard) by default. Then to yank (copy), you just use the regular `y` command, etc.

I found this behavior to be fairly annoying, though, as commands like `d` put the text they operate on into the default buffer, which meant I couldn't do a fast `dd` and paste a line from the internet, for example.

Comment: + is a clipboard regiser

Comment: Regarding your last point, `dd` means "cut one line", so that would be the expected behavior. In the rare case when you want to actually delete a line into oblivion, `"_dd` will do the trick.

Comment: also as @HamishDowner notes in his answer: The following will work only if `vim --version` indicates that you have `+xterm_clipboard` feature. If not, you will have to install extra packages or recompile vim with that feature added.

Answer (score 15):

I find the standard `"+gP` and `"+y` commands very difficult to use. So I've remapped `Ctrl-Y` for yanking into the clipboard and `Ctrl-P` to paste from the clipboard. Add this to `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <C-y> "+y
vnoremap <C-y> "+y
nnoremap <C-p> "+gP
vnoremap <C-p> "+gP
```

Answer (score 10):

When I checked my vim was not supporting clipboard:

```
vim --version | grep clip
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
```

I installed vim-gnome and then checked again

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
```

Now I am able to copy and paste using "+y and "+p respectively.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 instead install `vim-gtk3`

Comment: I think Arch Linux started building without this recently I think

Answer (score 8):

Just to add a non-vim-specific answer: You can use `Ctrl+Shift+C` to copy to the system clipboard in Ubuntu (if the functionality is provided by your terminal emulator, gnome-terminal for one provides it). `Ctrl+Shift+V` pastes to another terminal window, regular `Ctrl+V` pastes to a GUI app.

Additionally, if you select the text in the terminal, then middle-click, it will be pasted from the X11 clipboard.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. Just select with visual mode, copy with ctrl-shift-C, then paste in another app using Ctrl-shift-V ? The text doesn't get copied for me.

Comment: @ripper234: this does not work if you are using gvim. As crazy2be said, this functionality is from your terminal emulator.

Comment: @ripper234: 1) It is functionality provided by your terminal emulator (gnome-terminal for one provides it), 2) Ctrl+Shift+V is to paste *to the terminal*, GUI apps still use Ctrl+V as per usual. I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: if you use shift-control mousedrag - select text, copy pasting from one buffers window becomes easy.

Answer (score 8):

#### Hold down the SHIFT key and mouse select text to copy it.

Then paste in other program with `CTRL + v`.

Works in terminal on my Ubuntu 16.04. Not sure about `gvim` and other systems.

[image]

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: creative answer

Comment: For me it worked fine. Hold shift key before starting selecting. The selection gets a different color, the vim bar will not be "VISUAL" and the terminal menu will enable the Copy option.

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, I found the answer - it's written on the vim's menus.

```
"+y
```

Very intuitive.

Comment: Are you using `gvim`?

Comment: @nozimica- yeah

Comment: That's also available in vim running in an xterm or similar terminal emulator under X (if vim is compiled with the `+xterm_clipboard` feature).

Comment: This only works if gvim is installed with vim. If you its vim by itself, this solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you install the light version of vim, then you will not have the `+xterm_clipboard` feature on (`vim --version | grep xterm`), which is needed for using the `*` and `+` registers outside of vim.

To enable it, you must either compile vim yourself, or install a version of vim that comes with it preenabled. I used vim-gnome: `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`. If you perform `vim --version | grep xterm`, you will see that it is now `+xterm_clipboard`.

Now, try copying to the `+` and `*` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

#### This answer is for macOS users:

I'm adding this because none of the other answers that I tried here worked for me... but this one does! I cannot recall where I found this; I can't claim credit, but I will claim that it works for macOS, and it seems to be "native" to `vim` so it should work in other systems also:

1. From `vim` in your terminal window, enter visual mode by typing `v`
2. Select the text you want to copy using the mouse or glidepad
3. Type `"*y`; the selected text is copied to the system clipboard

You may now paste the copied text wherever it's needed.

IIRC, `"` tells `vim` to select a register; `*` specifies the system register; `y` is the `yank` (copy) command.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Windows 10, Terminal, PowerShell 7.3.2 (last version at the time)!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if anything works try to switch the terminal that wraps vim (if you are using vim from the terminal). I found that, for example, the clipboard is inaccessible by guake while is accessible from gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 And Above:

- Just select the text which you wanna be copy. And then click the centre roll button with your mouse and Go to the **clipboard**
- And do the same there too (click the centre roll button with your mouse).

It's 100% working in both `vim` and `tail` on Ubuntu.